Get pixel color from image for certain area - Use result as contrastColor
I have a label which is placed as a subview on an imageView. Depending on the color of the area where the label is set, I want to set the text color of the label as contrast. E. g. if the specific area of the image is dark, the text color should be white and vice versa.
Now, I have a method to get the dominantColor of the image. However, because of the contentMode of the imageView, the image doesn't take all the width of the imageView. The label is placed on a white edge but the cropped part of the imageView shows another area.
 func getDominantColorFromSubview(subview: UIView, within backgroundImageView: UIImageView) -> UIColor? {
    
    guard let image = backgroundImageView.image, let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
          
        return nil
       
    }

    // Ensure layout has been performed
    backgroundImageView.layoutIfNeeded()
    subview.layoutIfNeeded()

    // Convert the frame of the image view to the coordinate space of the backgroundImageView
    let imageViewFrameInImageView = subview.convert(subview.bounds, to: backgroundImageView)

    // Crop the image using the frame of the image view within the backgroundImageView
    guard let croppedImage = cgImage.cropping(to: imageViewFrameInImageView) else {
          
        return nil
    }

    let croppedUIImage = UIImage(cgImage: croppedImage)
    let dominantColor = croppedUIImage.getDominantColor()
    
    return dominantColor
}

this is how it is called
    let dominantColor = self.participantImageView.getDominantColorFromSubview(subview: self.participantImageView, within: self.eventImageView)
    self.participantImageView.setContrastingColor(color: dominantColor!)
                

and the setContrastingColor
 func setContrastingColor(color: UIColor) {
  
    if let imageView = self as? UIImageView {
        // Set contrasting color based on the brightness of the provided color
        if color.isDarkColor() {
          
            imageView.tintColor = .white
            
        } else {
         
            imageView.tintColor = .black
            
        }
    }
    // Check if the view is an instance of UILabel
    else if let label = self as? UILabel {
        // Set contrasting text color based on the brightness of the provided color
        if color.isDarkColor() {
            
            label.textColor = .white
            
        } else {
          
            label.textColor = .black
            
        }
    }
    
}

Any ideas how to improve this?

A common solution for showing a label over an area of varying color is to give the label a semi-transparent gray background. Then you don't need to change the text color and it is readable no matter what the underlying colors are.

Hi @HangarRash, nothing which I prefer to solve like that. I want to change the text color specifically

I understand, but changing the text color doesn't work well when the text covers both light and dark areas.

This is true @HangarRash. I still would like to try it out. Do you have a solution for me?
